# Scala Array manipulation task which requires two pointers [Scala]

Tags: scala

I have a task to update a scala array like this:

```
val input = Seq[2, 1, 5, 4, 5, 1, 8, 4]
```

`input` is the array which needs to be updated. `label` is the index from which the elements in the array should be updated accordingly. 
The updated rule for the elements is

```
new_value = the_current_value + value_of_last_labeled_elements
```

For example, if

```
val label = Seq(2)
```

then the desired result should be

```
input = Seq(2,1,5,4,5,1,8,4)
output = Seq(2,1,5,9,10,6,13,9)
```

There could be multiple labels:

```
val label = Seq(2,5)
```

Then the desired results should be:

```
input = Seq(2,1,5,4,5,1,8,4)
output = Seq(2,1,5,9,10,6,9,5)
```

The fifth element 5 was changed to 6, due to last labeled element is 5. From the sixth element, their values was updated by adding 1, due to the fifth elements is 1 in the original array.

I found this task can be easily handled in Java, by using two pointers in the loop. However, I have no idea how Scala could handle this.

Comment: How about a recursive function, taking some arguments for manipulation of (the rest of) the array?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is definitely possible, but I would prefer to use loop with two pointers, if there is no better scala style solution....

Comment: Sorry, had a cut'n'paste error in my code. Fixed. Your two pointers are just the heads of the Lists input and toShiftFrom (input, label).

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> def shiftFromIndexBy (input: List[Int], toShiftFrom: List[Int], shiftBy: Int = 0) : List [Int] = (input, toShiftFrom) match {
     |     case (Nil, _) => Nil
     |     case (x :: xs, Nil) => input.map (_ + shiftBy)
     |     case (x :: xs, y:: ys) => if (y == 0) x + shiftBy :: shiftFromIndexBy (xs, ys.map (_ - 1), x) else
     |         x + shiftBy :: shiftFromIndexBy (xs, toShiftFrom.map(_ - 1), shiftBy)
     | }
shiftFromIndexBy: (input: List[Int], toShiftFrom: List[Int], shiftBy: Int)List[Int]

scala> shiftFromIndexBy (input, label)
res19: List[Int] = List(2, 1, 5, 9, 10, 6, 13, 9)

scala> shiftFromIndexBy (input, List (2, 5))
res20: List[Int] = List(2, 1, 5, 9, 10, 6, 9, 5)
```

There are 3 cases, the last one with two subcases.

- Case 0: Input is empty. Done.
- Case 1: Input is valid, but no more shiftings will come from the index list, which is empty. Then perform the addition of the carried value to the rest of the List - done.
- Case 2a: We have values in the index list. If the first one is zero, we have to finally shift the first input value by the number carried. We get this first value x as new shiftBy value. The indexes have to decrease by one.
- Case 2b: The first index isn't zero, so we keep adding the old shiftBy-value, decreasing the index values in the rest of the list.

For large numbers of input and few index values, calculating the number of values to transform with the shiftBy value at once and decreasing the index values at once, could be considered. But first make things work, then make them fast.

For convenience I used Lists, not Seq for implementing.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to see if I could do it without recursion (and, of course, without pointers).

```
def updateAfterIndex(input:Seq[Int], label: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = {
  if (label.isEmpty) input
  else {
    val pad = Seq.fill(label.head + 1)(0) ++
      (label :+ input.length - 1).sliding(2)
        .flatMap { case Seq(a, b) => Seq.fill(b - a)(input(a)) }

    input.zip(pad).map(t => t._1 + t._2)
  }
}
```

It seems to work even for many examples of bad `label` content, e.g. an index out of range or in wrong order.

```
updateAfterIndex(Seq(2,1,5,4,5,1,8,4), Seq())     //res0: Seq[Int] = List(2, 1, 5, 4, 5, 1, 8, 4)
updateAfterIndex(Seq(2,1,5,4,5,1,8,4), Seq(2))    //res1: Seq[Int] = List(2, 1, 5, 9, 10, 6, 13, 9)
updateAfterIndex(Seq(2,1,5,4,5,1,8,4), Seq(2,5))  //res2: Seq[Int] = List(2, 1, 5, 9, 10, 6, 9, 5)
updateAfterIndex(Seq(2,1,5,4), Seq(5,2))          //res3: Seq[Int] = List(2, 1, 5, 4)
```